# How can I calculate the difference in days between two days stored as YYYYMMDD in a query?

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange, db2-400

I am writing a query where I need to calculate the number of days since a date that is stored in the database in the format "YYYYMMDD". Since this is not a Date datatype, I can't use native Date functions. What is the best way (performance-wise, readability-wise, etc.) to perform such a calculation in a SQL query.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Says he is using a ibm-midrange.  I'd say he's using DB2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best?  Convert that old table to use real date columns.

Next best?  Write a database function to convert YYMMDD to a real date. Alan Campin's iDate can help.  You'd end up with something akin to `select cvty2d(date1)-cvty2d(date2) from ...`

Better than nothing?  Write ugly SQL to convert the number to character, split the character up, add hyphens and convert THAT to a real date.  That beast would look something like

```
select 
  date(
     substr(char(date1),1,4) concat 
     '-' concat 
     substr (char(date1),5,2) concat 
     '-' concat 
     substr(char(date1),7,2)
  )  - 
  date(
     substr(char(date2),1,4) concat 
     '-' concat 
     substr (char(date2),5,2) concat 
     '-' concat 
     substr(char(date2),7,2)
  )   
from ...
```

Edit
The reason these gymnastics are necessary is that the DB2 DATE() function wants to see a string in the form of 'YYYY-MM-DD', with the hyphens being necessary.

Comment: Thanks. This is basically what I ended up doing after some further research. I'll post my final code here later.

Comment: Please note that the result as shown above is not the number of days. It is the (number of years * 10000) + (number of months * 100) + (number of days).

Comment: One would need to wrap the DATE() with DAYS() like this: DAYS(DATE(...)) - DAYS(DATE(...))

Answer (score 0):

Which version of SQL are you running?  SQL2008 has no issues with that format as a date datatype

```
Declare @something nvarchar(100)
set @Something = '20120112'

select dateadd(dd, 1, @Something)
select datediff(dd, @Something, getdate())
```

2012-01-13 00:00:00.000

118

Comment: This is not a SQL Server question.