# SQL query help for date

Tags: ibm-midrange, db2-400

I'm not the best at SQL, so I need some help. I have an existing query we use to pull data from DB2 for IBM i (AS400), and I want to modify it so it just pulls the last 6 months of data rather than constantly changing the range. I believe the OHSTDT field is saved on the server as YYYYMMDD.

```
WHERE GRPORDH.ODSTDT = GRPPHDR.OHSTDT AND GRPORDH.ODGRPH = GRPPHDR.OHGRPH AND (GRPPHDR.OHSTDT Between {d '2013-01-01'} And {d '2015-06-01'})
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select last 6 months from news table using MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8941377/how-to-select-last-6-months-from-news-table-using-mysql)

Comment: I searched Stackoverflow for 'db2 number to date' and came up with [convert decimal to date during where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606476/convert-decimal-to-date-during-where-clause/8607127#8607127) and [How can I calculate the difference in days between two days stored as YYYYMMDD in a query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522232/how-can-i-calculate-the-difference-in-days-between-two-days-stored-as-yyyymmdd-i/10522735#10522735)

Answer (score 1):

Build or download a function that converts Date types to Numeric.

iDate is the one I use:
www.think400.dk/downloads.htm

Then your query becomes:

```
WHERE GRPORDH.ODSTDT = GRPPHDR.OHSTDT 
  AND GRPORDH.ODGRPH = GRPPHDR.OHGRPH 
  AND GRPPHDR.OHSTDT between ConvertToIDate(CURRENT_DATE - 6 MONTHS,'*CCYMD')
                         AND ConvertToIDate(CURRENT_DATE,'*CCYMD')
```

Note that the alternate form:

```
WHERE GRPORDH.ODSTDT = GRPPHDR.OHSTDT 
  AND GRPORDH.ODGRPH = GRPPHDR.OHGRPH 
  AND iDate(GRPPHDR.OHSTDT) between CURRENT_DATE - 6 MONTHS
                         AND CURRENT_DATE
```

which uses the iDate() function to convert from a numeric date to a date date is not the prefered method.  It will work, and you'll find lots of examples that do this.  But it performs poorly for two reasons.

- more conversions
- indexes over OHSTDT can not be used.

Both the iDate() function and the ConvertToIDate() function are available in the iDate library you can download at the link above.